# Laravel 4: Error: Popover requires tooltip.js

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, less

I am using [Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site](https://github.com/andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site). I have this issue loading javascript files:  **Error: Popover requires tooltip.js** It seems that is not causing majors problems but I am losing functionality.

[image]

Checking source code we can see that **popover is loaded first and before than tooltip** file.

```
<!-- Javascripts -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/4e833b1b206008719982ee4bd4edd6f2/popover-49fe37fdd6b1d004e71a46c3650d6e3b.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/4e833b1b206008719982ee4bd4edd6f2/tab-49fe37fdd6b1d004e71a46c3650d6e3b.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/4e833b1b206008719982ee4bd4edd6f2/alert-49fe37fdd6b1d004e71a46c3650d6e3b.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/4e833b1b206008719982ee4bd4edd6f2/transition-49fe37fdd6b1d004e71a46c3650d6e3b.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/4e833b1b206008719982ee4bd4edd6f2/modal-49fe37fdd6b1d004e71a46c3650d6e3b.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/4e833b1b206008719982ee4bd4edd6f2/scrollspy-49fe37fdd6b1d004e71a46c3650d6e3b.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/4e833b1b206008719982ee4bd4edd6f2/carousel-49fe37fdd6b1d004e71a46c3650d6e3b.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/4e833b1b206008719982ee4bd4edd6f2/dropdown-49fe37fdd6b1d004e71a46c3650d6e3b.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/4e833b1b206008719982ee4bd4edd6f2/tooltip-49fe37fdd6b1d004e71a46c3650d6e3b.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/4e833b1b206008719982ee4bd4edd6f2/collapse-49fe37fdd6b1d004e71a46c3650d6e3b.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/4e833b1b206008719982ee4bd4edd6f2/button-49fe37fdd6b1d004e71a46c3650d6e3b.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/4e833b1b206008719982ee4bd4edd6f2/affix-49fe37fdd6b1d004e71a46c3650d6e3b.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/assets/js/wysihtml5/wysihtml5-0.3.0-5f4b6ad2a53f7fc45751886caf6076e2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/assets/js/wysihtml5/bootstrap-wysihtml5-5f4b6ad2a53f7fc45751886caf6076e2.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/assets/js/datatables-bootstrap-5f4b6ad2a53f7fc45751886caf6076e2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/assets/js/datatables.fnReloadAjax-5f4b6ad2a53f7fc45751886caf6076e2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/assets/js/jquery.colorbox-5f4b6ad2a53f7fc45751886caf6076e2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/assets/js/prettify-5f4b6ad2a53f7fc45751886caf6076e2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/assets/js/jquery.uploadfile-88e9f41770fc597c379b2a75086bcb0f.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.dev/assets/compiled/admin/assets/js/common-75a4c5198cfe0c4468991a6000253513.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.wysihtml5').wysihtml5();
$(prettyPrint);
</script>
```

**Question**: is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I said it `popover is loaded first and before than tooltip`. These are compiled files. They are not manually loaded.

Comment: Have you tried to load tooltip first?

Comment: Yes, but as the title says, this a a Laravel issue. In Laravel as ror, and other frameworks, assets are precompiled before serve to client. So it should work if we can have more control over the order of files served.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant php code you are using to echo these assets?

Comment: @user1669496 I am discovering that this seems to be an issue just related to `Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site` that I used as base to start learning this framework. Mainly about `bootstrap` and `basset`. Thanks.-

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. The reason that happens is because basset loads the resources in order by name. and since p comes before t obviously it gets loaded afterwards coming up with the error. Hacking your way around the problem simply rename tooltip with to atolltip in vendors/twbs/bootstrap/js or instead requiring the directory to load the files in basset config you require each single js file in the order you want. The second option i did not test but should work.